# How to display the login username and the search text field under each other

Tags: css, html

I have the following layout html to show the login username and a search input text:-

```
<section id="login" class="navbar-search pull-right">

<span class="username"><i class="icon-user"></i><strong> @User.Identity.Name.Substring(User.Identity.Name.IndexOf("\\") + 1)</strong></span>

<form  method="GET" action="@Url.Action("Search", "Home")">

<input  placeholder=".." name="searchTerm2" data-autocomplete-source= "@Url.Action("AutoComplete", "Home")" type="text"  /> 

</form>

</section>
```

and the related css class:-

```
.navbar-search {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Currently I am having the following layout issue; is that the username will be out of the layout as follow:-
[image]

So my question is how I can modify my current layout to show the text search field under the login username, and to have the username to the right side of the screen .

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Specify a width for your section login (large enough to contain input search or the display name), put your span with username display as a block and float it right. Something like this

```
#login{ width: 300px }
.navbar-search{width: 300px}
.username{
  display: block;
  float: right;

}
```

Should do the trick